# Selenium how to click 'p' tag within div

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

This is the html. I need to click on the "addBtn".

```
<div class="shuffle-container">
<p class="addBtn"></p>
<p class="removeBtn"></p >
</div>
```

Driver highlights the button related to class "addBtn", but the click event is not happening.

This is my selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("addBtn")).click();
```

Comment: My experience with Selenium for Java is not so big. (Only have experience with FF-Addon or the suitable PHPUnit-Extension) Did you try to call `driver.findElements(By.className("addBtn"))` (consider the "s")? Maybe it clicks only the first "p.addBtn"-Element which isn't your expected one...

Comment: Is there some text in `p` tags? and, please add the exception you are getting

Comment: Here is what this scenario is:   1. Launch the page 2. add data into the text field. 3. Select the data that was added, and Click on the "addBtn" to move that data into another text field.

Comment: @Saifur, there is no text in the p tag

Comment: So look at the answer by Don Bottstein

Answer (score 2):

From the [API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click%28%29):

> There are some preconditions for an element to be clicked. The element must be visible and it must have a height and width greater then **0**. Since your **p** element has no content, the width/height is **0**.

Comment: I am able to click on the "addBtn" if i use a different scenario, i.e. not add data into the text field and then click. If the data is already there, then the click event occurs...

Comment: @Insane If you add width/height through css, that should be sufficient to allow clicking of the element. I'm not clear on what the failing scenario is. Are you getting a selenium exception (e.g., org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible) or do you have a js event listener on the element that isn't getting executed?